# Excel: Sum rows of numbers between certain values in adjacent column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have basic data files from a lab instrument that may look something like this (simplified):

[image: data]

Column B has random data values (may include zeros) and column C will have  integers from 0 up to lets say 6 (in reality max value may vary). Total number of rows with 0 in column C varies between positive integers from run to run.

I need to sum up data in column B in such a way that sum= sum of values in B that occur between "(n-1)" and "n" with "n" included, where "n" is a positive integer in column C. Hopefully this is more clear from the picture. Is there way to do that with a simple formula? Note that for last entry I need to include the summation of values in B occurring after the last integer in C. I currently do this by hand but I am hoping there is formula I could use or a simple macro. I know this can be done with VBA but I don't have experience with it. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In F2:

```
=IF(C2>0,IF(COUNTIF(C3:C1039986,">0")=0,SUM(B:B),SUM($B$2:B2))-SUM($F$1:F1),"")
```

And copy/drag down.

[image]

Comment: Very good approach that uses the sums you previously calculated. I was already thinking about using multiple index-match functions, but your answer is way better!

Comment: This is very simple and elegant. Thank you so much, as it will save me hours of work!